# Broadcast before BOOT_COMPLETED?

Tags: android, permissions, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

Is there a way to detect that the device is turned on but the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast? I know I can catch the Broadcast with a BOOT_COMPLETED RECEIVER, but is there anything that is fired directly after device is turned on, for example if the user turns on the device and the System Pin request is appearing? I checked in Samsung Galaxy S3 and the BOOT_COMPLETED is only fired after user has logged into the sytsem with the pin number, but I need a way to detect before the pin is entered.

Explanation: No fear, don´t want to do anything evil :) , just want to practise my first security app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is **NO**, there is no system-level global broadcast action sent before `BOOT_COMPLETED`. There is an action called `com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON` available on HTC devices which probably wont be of any use in your situation, but its all there is.

That is all.

Comment: unfortunately I have to accept Your answer, unfortunately because there is no way and You are wright :( . But many thanks to pointing that out and mention about the htc QUICK_REBOOT_POWERON.

Comment: You're welcome ... though I'm interested in learning what exactly you were trying to achieve

Comment: I wanted to add a security request before the system pin is requestet....like a kind of multiple requests to get sure nobody can crack one pin....